# On a particular drawing, a pulley wheel can be described by the equation $x^2+y^2=100$. For more please check the pic of the problems

Tags: tangent-line

On a particular drawing, a pulley wheel can be described by the equation $x^2+y^2=100$. For more please check the pic of the problems

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XUnjj.png]

Comment: Please share your work and where you faced problems

Comment: please check this link  https://i.stack.imgur.com/XUnjj.png

Comment: ^Thats the question again.

Comment: yes. this is the question

Comment: I asked what have you tried so far. Where you faced problems while trying

Comment: Please take the time to enter your question as text. Images are neither searchable nor accessible to screen readers, nor do they show up in summaries. I find it hard to imagine that it was less work to take a picture, crop it, upload it and link it into your question that it would have been to type in those three sentences. For formatting mathematical expressions, see the MathJax quick reference [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: I have solved it. Now no need to write. Thanks